# Find out how offical Debian Stretch AMI was created/scripted

Tags: linux, debian, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

We're using the offical Debian Stretch [AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B073HW9SP3?qid=1529555224858&sr=0-2&ref_=srh_res_product_title).

Doing some investigation, it's clear that some hardening and optimizations have been done specific to the AMI for AWS/EC2 use.

How can I find out the specifics of what's been included/excluded in this AMI? (Is there a clear channel to communicate this question w/ the Debian team, or is the information is out there? If this was simply a community AMI I wouldn't expect much, but since it's from Debian, I'd hope some documentation is floating around).

Note: I'd like to avoid scripting our own AMI for now. And clearly some time, effort, and hardening has been put into this Debian AMI, and it'd be great to know what all went into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First result of a google search for `debian ami` is [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Cloud/AmazonEC2Image), which contains a github [link](https://github.com/andsens/bootstrap-vz) to the script that generates AMI images.

Comment: Thanks - and looks like he's an official member of the team. https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Cloud Was just looking for some validation around using the AMI here. Thank you.